# Keycloak: is MIT Kerberos client needed?

Tags: kerberos, keycloak

I am using the keycloak single sign on server and want to enable the kerberos authentication
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_kerberos

In the documentation they say I have to install a MIT kerberos client on the keycloak server.

As far as I know that the JDK has classes for the kerberos protocol. For example that was one of the exceptions I had

```
Caused by: KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96
at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:278)
at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:149)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108)
at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:829)
... 93 more
```

And here is also a reference link.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/single-sign-using-kerberos-java1.htm#JSSEC-GUID-D4230975-A28B-4532-B1DD-3C7219A4867F

So My question what is actually the MIT Kerberos client? is it part of the JDK? or is it a library on which the JDK depends? 
BTW I am running the keycloak server on a windows machine and did not have to install any extra client.

Comment: **1.** The MIT implementation of Kerberos protocol has existed for longer than Java **2.** The Java implementation of Kerberos is JVM-dependent _(e.g. IBM Java has different options for JAAS than OpenJDK or Sun/Oracle JRE have)_ **3.** the "standard" Java implementation is incomplete and brittle _(e.g. it does not support renewable tickets, never stores service tickets in the cache, etc)_

Comment: For the record, you van browse the "reference" for Kerberos in the Hadoop ecosystem (which partly uses, partly overrides the Java implementation) >> https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/jdk_versions.html

Comment: Side note: decades ago, the NSA did not allow Java to "export" AES encryption to every country. That's history, but up to Java 8 the Sun/Oracle JVM does not support AES by default, you must enable it manually... OpenJDK and recent versions of Sun/Oracle JDK don't have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, the MIT Kerberos client is an OS package, which includes C libraries and command-line utilities such as `kinit`, `klist`, `ktutil`

- on RedHat / CentOS / etc  `sudo yum install krb5-workstation`
- on Ubuntu / etc `sudo apt-get install krb5-user`

---

On Windows, the OS comes with the *Microsoft* implementation of Kerberos (as used in Active Directory) which includes a ton of custom extensions and oddities, including a specific "LSA cache" for credentials which is managed by the OS (and which may not be accessible by non-Microsoft apps, depending on OS type and whether or not you have tweaked a registry flag).
But you can install the ***MIT Kerberos for Windows*** app that bridges the gap between "standard" and "Microsoft" Kerberos implementations. Somehow.

WARNING >> On Windows you may end with three different `klist.exe` utilities, which list different ticket caches with different options -- the one bundled with Windows, the one bundled with Java, the one bundled with *MIT Kerberos for Windows* app; mind your PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and informatory answer. But I wonder if a server like keycloak is implemented in Java, which kerberos client it will use. Theoretically it will use the Java client, or so I guess considering the above exception. Currently I am using keycloak on windows. May be I have to try it on Linux, firstly without installing a kerberos client to see if the openjdk client is enough.

Comment: Even worse: a _service_ and a _client_ do different things with their "Kerberos client" >> the _service_ authenticates with a SPN and checks incoming service tickets; the _client_ authenticates with a UPN, gets a service ticket for the appropriate service/host combination(s) -- i.e. to the appropriate SPN(s )--, and submit the ticket(s) to the _service(s)_